# Yii2 Logout after Login with a custom otp

Tags: php, yii2

I don't think the following problem is a general Yii2 problem, but maybe I'm wrong.

We offer our customers a possibility to log in via GET using an OTP.
This OTP is valid once and then deleted.

e.g. https://example.com/?otp=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

If I send the link to the customer and he clicks on this link via a web client, a new tab is opened, the user is logged in and a refresh is made.
Unfortunately, this kills the session.

However, if he copies the link from the email and pastes it to a new tab on his own and runs it, the user is logged in correctly and there are no problems.

What could be the problem? Anyone have an idea or a hint?

Comment: Probably he has another session open under a different session token

Comment: I'm not sure using GET in this case is good idea. Some clients might try to display preview of page which would essentially make the OTP token already used when the user tries to open the link.